# When do you use の to join nouns and colours/adjectives?

Tags: grammar, particles, particle-の

When do you use の to join nouns and colours? I know that green pencil is 緑{みどり}の鉛筆 【えんぴつ】but I'm not sure if it's the same for other colours or adjectives.

Comment: `or adjectives` Are you referring to i-adjectives or na-adjectives generally? Or the six colors that have i-adjective counterparts (黒い, 白い, 赤い, 青い, 茶色い, 黄色い)?

Comment: I mean all colours including the ones with い counterparts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> When do you use の to join nouns and colours/adjectives?

Adjectives are made to modify a noun, so they don't need の: ex. 高い空.
Nouns basically need の to be connected to another noun: ex. 今日の天気.

For colours, it's something hard to tell if we don't know, but [this page](https://matome.naver.jp/odai/2145197788402587901) is affirming that we have only limited colours that can be used as adjectives.
Only four of い type: 赤い, 青い, 白い, 黒い, and two of ～色い type: 黄色い, 茶色い.
Ex: 白い雲, 茶色い写真, etc.

Other colors are nouns and always need （色）の to connect to another noun.
Ex: 緑の, 緑色の, ピンクの, ブルーの, 黄金色の, etc.